# Is Ubuntu compatible with my 32 bit windows 7 system?

Tags: windows-7, 32-bit, compatibility

I'm brand new to Ubuntu and not tech savvy like the rest of this group apperantly is. I have an older machine (32 bit windows 7) and I'm curious about Ubuntu and want to try it out, if it works well I'll install it on my Toshiba laptop (32 bit windows vista home premium) next!

Comment: The question is unanswerable in its current form. Please add some hardware info, or just try Ubuntu from CD/USB.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu and windows are separated operating systems. There is for sure a 32 bit image of ubuntu avaliable [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest). Please note Ubuntu and windows will run in different partitions and the partitioning procedure **CAN LEAD TO DATA LOSS** if you don't know what you are doing. Please come back here or go to #Ubuntu at irc.freenode.org in order to get a clear picture of the procedures involved in [Dualbooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot).